# Query X amount of days in the past

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Running MySql and Yii I need to change a relational query that currently finds records for the current month to find all records for the last 45 days.

This is my current query:

```
    'itemCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Item', 'ItemId', 
              'condition'=>'SUBSTRING(DateMoved FROM 1 FOR 7) = 
              SUBSTRING(current_date - INTERVAL 0 month FROM 1 FOR 7)  
              AND Status="W"'),
```

I have tried modifying this and tried a different approach using strtotime but neither approach is working.  Using self::STAT can I find all records for the last 45 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query to get records of last 45 days

```
SELECT * FROM table_name t 
WHERE t.DateMoved >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -45 DAY);
```

With your code

```
'itemCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Item', 'ItemId', 
'condition'=>'DateMoved >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -45 DAY)
AND Status="W"'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INTERVAL 45 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

*Let me know if you have any further questions.*

Answer (score 0):

For getting records for last N day you may use simple SQL query condition like this:

```
DateMoved >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)
```

Other words - compare record date with current date substract 45 days